# Combination: Open mailto and form submit

Tags: forms, post, onclick, mailto

This combination of an open mailto window with a post form to test.php on one click does not work. Any suggestions?

```
<form id="myForm" action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="someName" value="helloworld" />
<a href="mailto:..." 
onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">
Submit
</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below solution to ignore `href` attribute and focus on using `onclick` only to do what you need

```js
function submit() {
  window.open('mailto:mail@example.org', '_blank');
  document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="test.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="someName" value="helloworld" />
  <a href="#" onclick="return submit();">
      Submit
    </a>
</form>
```

And if you need to use both `href` and `onclick` check below alternative solution

```js
function submit() {
  document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="test.php" method="post" onsubmit="alert('Ok')">
  <input type="hidden" name="someName" value="helloworld" />
  <a href="mailto:mail@example.org" target="_blank" onclick="return submit();">
      Submit
    </a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Wael: Thanks. The second solution is equivalent to this.

```
<form id="myForm2" action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="someName" value="helloworld" />
<a href="mailto:mail@example.org" target="_blank" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm2').submit();">Submit 2</a>
</form>
```

The missing target attribute was the issue.

In Firefox it works as required. In Chrome it leads to 
1. Opens the mail client
2. Posts to test.php
3. Opens a new browser tab with url mailto:mail@example.org (and focus)

With your first solution it is the same. How to avoid 3.?

Comment: As you used `target="_blank"` opens a new browser tab, and as you have mail client app it will open.

Comment: Yes, but without target="_blank" the submit does not work.

Comment: Yes, as submit will redirect the page and `href` also will navigate in the same page if you did not use `target="_blank"`